# Python has stopped working(APPCRASH) Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

When I try to build Linear Regression model with training data in Jupyter notebook, python has stopped working, with error as shown below. I am using Anaconda 3.5 on windows7, Python 3.6 version.

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version:  3.6.4150.1013
  Application Timestamp:    5a5e439a
  Fault Module Name:    mkl_core.dll
  Fault Module Version: 2018.0.1.1
  Fault Module Timestamp:   59d8a332
  Exception Code:   c000001d
  Exception Offset: 0000000001a009a3
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 7071
  Additional Information 2: 70718f336ba4ddabacde4b6b7fbe73e3
  Additional Information 3: de32
  Additional Information 4: de328b4df988a86fd2d750fb0942dbd1

I am not able to get any help from google when I search with this error, even I tried
1 Uninstalled and again installed
2. Ran below commands but no use
   conda update conda
   conda update ipython ipython-notebook ipython-qtconsole

I suspect this error related to Windows, but not sure how to fix it.

Thanks,
Sagar.

Answer (score 0):

Updated all the libraries to latest version in Anaconda and try.

I was facing a similar situation when I was running the code for Convolutional Neural Network in Spyder under Anaconda environment (Windows 7) I was getting following error

> Problem Event Name:  APPCRASH
>     Application Name: pythonw.exe
>     Fault Module Name:    StackHash
>     Exception Code:   c0000005
>     OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1

I updated all the libraries to latest version in Anaconda and the problem is resolved.